# How to use CASE with 2 table in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two data tables Members and Transaction

sample:

**Members**

```
Members_Id | Name |  Adress  |rental_amount |
---------------------------------------------
    A01    | John | New York |     4        |
    A02    | Mark | German   |     2        |
    A03    | Ika  | France   |     5        |
```

**Transaction**

```
NumberTransac |Number_plate|  Discount|  Price  |Members_Id |
---------------------------------------------------------------
      1       | AA8866DG   |     0    | $90000  |   A01     |
      2       | AB5536HG   |     0    | $8000   |   A01     |
      3       | BG7677HJ   |     0    | $70000  |   A03     |
```

I want to calculated the field rental_amount and Discounts
using CASE

If the number of rent> 3 then the field "Discount" will be added '100000'

```
IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members.rental_amount WHERE ) > 3 INSERT INTO     Transaction(Discount) VALUES ('100000') ELSE INSERT INTO Transaction(Discount) VALUES ('100000') ; GO
```

I am still confused how appliances in sql if else ... please help me .. thanks

Comment: number of rented determined by what field?  Members_ID?

Comment: what should happen if they are 3 or less?  what would discount be?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE transaction
SET discount = 100000
WHERE Members_Id IN
   (SELECT Members_Id
    FROM members 
    WHERE rental_amount > 3 )
```

Comment: I think you want **SET discount = 100000 + discount** or something, because the user wants to add 100000 to the discount.  Other than that, I think this is correct.